# MySQL - Where can I find metrics on the performance of Blob vs file system?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance

I know and understand that there are performance hits in storing blob data in the database, but the blob portion of the data is going to be rarely retrieved/viewed, it is for smaller data (the vast majority under 256k with a max of 10mb), it is not going to be used by most customers, and the total rows is expected to be relatively low, very likely under half a million, if not less. Also some of the data is dynamic and can change for some users, as in it's not static images. In other words we're at the edge of whether or not it's worth it.

I keep reading that it's better to store in the file system but I can't find actual metrics that show the performance difference, just people repeating each other without any concrete proof or metrics. For us it may be worth the performance cost in exchange for being fully ACID as well as guaranteeing that all our backups are completely synched.

***That being said does anyone know or have any real world metrics to show the performance difference between storing items as blobs vs in the file system.*** I'm trying to understand if the performance penalty is worth it or not rather than blindly following the general rule of thumb and after spending at least 2-3 hours I've yet to be able to see anyone show any actual numbers...

**UPDATE:** MySQL with an InnoDB table. The actual data table has a link to the blob data table, so the blob is not in the main able and is only retrieved when need be to avoid any I/O issues. In other words instead of the path to the data on the filesystem, it's an ID to another table with only blobs. How does that compare in terms of performance? Is it 25% worse? Is it 100%? Is it 200-500%? Is it 1000%?

If the cost is only 100%-200% it is probably worth it for us because again the data is rarely retrieved. So even if we had say 10,000 concurrent users, maybe only 50 users would be retrieving their blob data concurrently at best. Yes the data is specific to each user, it isn't images.

Comment: Better post this at dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I thought about it but it's borderline because it will have a much bigger impact in terms of the code than the DB itself...

Comment: That is correct, however on dba.stackexchange more people are concerned with just these kind of topics. The code "only" results from your choices.

Comment: Have you tried testing in your environment?  That is the best way to truly know the difference for YOUR application.